# How to become a developer approved by LinkedIn to use LinkedIn's Connections API?

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to use LinkedIn's Connections API to retrieve the 1st degree connections of users registering on my application. But, "The use of this API is restricted to those developers approved by LinkedIn and subject to applicable data restrictions in their agreements.". Has anyone experience in getting approved and what are the main points to consider before applying? And, how can we apply? Thanks!

Comment: did you find a way to become a developers approved by LinkedIn?

Comment: I still looking for how to get approved by LinkedIn.

Comment: Did anyone found how to get approved by LinkedIn and is there any subscription for using the API's

Answer (score 6):

To access any APIs you'll first need to setup a business page on LinkedIn [(instructions here)](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/710/create-a-linkedin-page?lang=en) for app verification then head to [the developer page](https://www.linkedin.com/developers) to create an app

To access their restricted APIs you'll want to reach out to their support team [via the contact us page](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/solve/contact) and request access; specifically looking for a `Relationship Manager` if you have an existing business relationship or a `Business Development` contact per the [compliance docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/):

```
The use of these APIs is restricted to developers approved by LinkedIn.
Reach out to your LinkedIn Relationship Manager or
Business Development contact as you will need to meet certain criteria and sign an API agreement with data restrictions
in order to use this integration.
```